# How can I maintain the order of adding items in react web app?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I create an order of adding items. I should be able to add one after the other item during on click. By default it should display the `Textarea` first and then `blockquote` ( see below )
a) When a user click on Text area button, it should add one after the blockquote.
b) Then when the user clicks on Code area button, it should add after Textarea. Could someone please advise ?

CSB link:  https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-worker-26jztf?file=/src/App.js

Something similar >> Expected behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/nve8qdbu/8/

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const blogListData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    heading: "React state",
    date: "22-May-2022",
    tag: "React",
    count: "3"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    heading: "Cypress testing detailss",
    date: "22-May-2022",
    tag: "Cypress",
    count: "5"
  }
];

const Admin = () => {
  const [createImageTag, setImageTag] = useState("");
  const [fields, setFields] = useState([{ value: null }]);
  const [createCode, setCreateCode] = useState([{ value: null }]);
  const [blogList, setBlogList] = useState([]);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    reset
  } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    setBlogList(blogListData);
  }, []);

  function handleChangeTextArea(i, event) {
    const values = [...fields];
    values[i].value = event.target.value;
    setFields(values);
  }

  function handleChangeCode(i, event) {
    const codeValues = [...createCode];
    codeValues[i].value = event.currentTarget.innerText;
    setCreateCode(codeValues);
  }

  function handleTextAreaAdd() {
    const values = [...fields];
    values.push({ value: null });
    setFields(values);
  }

  function handleCodeAreaAdd() {
    const codeValues = [...createCode];
    codeValues.push({ value: null });
    setCreateCode(codeValues);
  }

  function handleImageAreaAdd() {
    const image = [...createImageTag];
    image.push({ value: null });
    setCreateCode(image);
  }

  function handleRemoveText(i) {
    const values = [...fields];
    values.splice(i, 1);
    setFields(values);
  }

  function handleRemoveCode(i) {
    const codeValues = [...createCode];
    codeValues.splice(i, 1);
    setCreateCode(codeValues);
  }

  const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("loginEmail");
  };

  return (
    <div id="App">
      <div className="parent">
        <div className="adminSection">
          <h1>Create a new blog</h1>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="logout">
              <img
                src="/images/logout.png"
                alt="Logout"
                onClick={handleLogout}
              ></img>
            </div>

            <div className="createBlogSection">
              <div className="row">
                <button
                  onClick={() => handleTextAreaAdd()}
                  className="textAreaBtn"
                >
                  Text Area
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => handleCodeAreaAdd()}
                  className="codeAreaBtn"
                >
                  Code Area
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => handleImageAreaAdd()}
                  className="imageAreaBtn"
                >
                  Add Image
                </button>
              </div>{" "}
              <br></br>
              <div className="row">
                {fields.map((field, idx) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={`${field}-${idx}`} className="dtextArea">
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => handleRemoveText(idx)}
                        className="closeElement"
                      >
                        X
                      </button>
                      <textarea
                        type="text"
                        id="blogtext"
                        placeholder="Enter your text here"
                        className="defaultTextArea"
                        {...register("blogtext", {
                          required: true,
                          minLength: {
                            value: 25,
                            message: "Minimum length of 25 letters"
                          }
                        })}
                        value={field.value || ""}
                        onChange={(e) => handleChangeTextArea(idx, e)}
                      />
                      <span className="validationmsg">
                        {errors.blogtext &&
                          errors.blogtext.type === "required" && (
                            <span>Blog text is required !</span>
                          )}
                        {errors.blogtext && (
                          <span>{errors.blogtext.message}</span>
                        )}
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                {createCode.map((code, idx) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={`${code}-${idx}`} className="dCodeArea">
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => handleRemoveCode(idx)}
                        className="closeElement"
                      >
                        X
                      </button>
                      <blockquote
                        type="text"
                        id="blogCode"
                        contentEditable="true"
                        className="codehighlight"
                        placeholder="Enter your code here"
                        {...register("blogCode", {
                          required: true
                        })}
                        value={code.value || ""}
                        onInput={(e) => handleChangeCode(idx, e)}
                      />
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="submitSection">
                  <input type="submit" className="submitBtn" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="blogListSection">
          <h1>Edit blogs</h1>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="editBlogSection">
              {blogList.map(({ id, heading, count }) => (
                <a
                  key={id}
                  href="https://www.testingsite.com/"
                  className="blogitems"
                >
                  <pre>
                    <span>{count}</span> {heading}
                  </pre>
                </a>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Admin;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

react is designed for components . each of your list elements should be refactored by a component.then it would be easier. i think a single react component could do the trick